# Compiling java project with multiple dirs and dependency hierarchy

Tags: java, compiler-errors, javac

**Note:** I can successfully compile everything else besides RegisterTest.java

I have the following project structure. I want to compile this using javac only, no build tools, no IDEs.
Each file is in a package corresponding to their directory structure, for example `Drink.java` is in Kassensystem/AbstractProducts which translates to `package Kassensystem.AbstractProducts;`

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eOR5.png)

All abstract products implement the common interface Product which is in the Interfaces folder, so they naturally `import Kassensystem.Interfaces.*`. Finally the Products are the concrete classes derived from the abstract product classes, so they in turn `import Kassensystem.AbstractProducts.*`. Finally the Register class just calculates some prices and only depends on the Product interface. RegisterTest should test the whole system and instantiates some concrete classes and passes them to Register.

So the dependency hierarchy is as follows:
[Dependency Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wgGO.png)

I'm having trouble compiling this, how would I need to set the classpath to get the right dependency order (note I'm not using jar files)?
I tried setting the classpath such that the most abstract classes come first (Interfaces -> Abstract Classes -> Concrete Products -> Register) but it's always complaining at the import statements, that the package does not exist.

```
$ javac -cp "Interfaces/*.class:AbstractProducts/*.class:Products/*.class"  RegisterTest.java
RegisterTest.java:3: error: package Kassensystem.Products does not exist
import Kassensystem.Products.*;
^
RegisterTest.java:4: error: package Kassensystem.Interfaces does not exist
import Kassensystem.Interfaces.*;
^
RegisterTest.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        var products = new Product[] { new Tomato(), new TomatoJuice() };
                           ^
  symbol:   class Product
  location: class RegisterTest
RegisterTest.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        var products = new Product[] { new Tomato(), new TomatoJuice() };
                                           ^
  symbol:   class Tomato
  location: class RegisterTest
RegisterTest.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        var products = new Product[] { new Tomato(), new TomatoJuice() };
                                                         ^
  symbol:   class TomatoJuice
  location: class RegisterTest
RegisterTest.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
        double total = Register.scan(products);
                       ^
  symbol:   variable Register
  location: class RegisterTest
6 errors
```

Comment: Hint: -cp takes direcories (containing .class files) or names of .jar files as arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Getting the same error, though. ```$ javac -cp Interfaces/:AbstractProducts/:Products/ Register.java
Register.java:3: error: package Kassensystem.Interfaces does not exist
import Kassensystem.Interfaces.Product;```. The specified folders indeed contain .class files.

Comment: You should not put the *.class files in the same directory as your sources. Use the -d flag to output them in a directory out of your sources then just use -cp to this directory